# jasmine globally use httpClientTestingModule

Tags: angular, jasmine

Is there a way to globally inject httpClientTestingModule for each Testbed?

I unfortunately have a situation in which I cannot tell for certain when an XHR request is being made. My working theory is that it is a race condition based on randomized test execution caused by a library which we have in almost every component, (though I wouldn't claim to understand the problem and how this can be happening...)

With over 800 tests finding the bad apples proves to be rather difficult, and I would like to avoid implementing the module by hand over 100 times. Is there a nuke-em-all solution? A test should never go through to HttpCilent, so I thought maybe there is a global import command you can specify, in p.e. test.ts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes we can.

In **test.ts** we provide `HttpClientTestingModule` globally so that you don't have to import it in every TestBed setup:

```js
  getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
    [BrowserDynamicTestingModule, HttpClientTestingModule],
    platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
  );
```

then after that you can add an afterEach in **test.ts** that will call the verify method:

```js
afterEach(() => {
  const httpController = TestBed.get(
    HttpTestingController
  ) as HttpTestingController;
  httpController.verify();
});
```

Note: in recent version of Angular swap *TestBed.get* with *TestBed.inject*.

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kyvzmt?file=src%2Fmain.ts. (Notice *main.ts* and *http-client.specs.ts*)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed! In my case, the verification in afterEach is not necessary. Is there any downside on skipping it? Like, can tests get stuck in execution stage and have to be cleaned manually (like with a function like discardPeriodicTasks (something like discardAsyncTasks)?)

Comment: I assumed that you'd need to call to verify() but it's optional, it only check if all requests for the current test case have been resolved. So you can drop it.
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/cb31dbc75ca4141d61cec3ba6e60505198208a0a/packages/common/http/testing/src/backend.ts#L123